# Remove row "A" where its 'destination' value is already exist in the 'source' value on row "B"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2012

Apologies for the confusing title. I have a basically 'route' table from point A to point B, from the image below we can see that ID 1622 and ID 1634 is basically the same because once a certain point is visited it cannot be visited again (1-way), and I'd like to remove either one so there's only one row from **B708** to **B733**.

[image: table image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.source = t.destination and t1.destination = t.source and t1.id < t1.id
)
```

Basically when two "mirror" rows exists, this retains the one that has the smallest `id`, and dismisses the other one.